# Implement glitter effect in iOS Camera?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, video-capture

I have implement glitter effect for capture camera photo and recored videos in iOS devices.

.

I have prefer many links for implement glitter effect in photo, but I have implement in active camera in capture photo or recored video times.

.

Give some suggestion and library for implement glitter effect in active camera in iOS devices....

Comment: I have implement this type Glitter effect http://www.revelist.com/beauty-howtos/kirakira-app/8076/and-my-nail-art-was-taken-to-another-level-of-perfection/6

Comment: can you please share the process of how you did that?

Answer (score 2):

You might use Twinkle. `Twinkle` is available and recommended for installation using the Cocoa dependency manager CocoaPods. You can also simply copy the `Twinkle.swift` file into your Xcode project.

```
import Twinkle
import UIKit

// UIView extension
let view: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 640, height: 480))
self.view.addSubview(view)
view.twinkle()

// class function
Twinkle.twinkle(myView)
```

Here's a github link for downloading: https://github.com/piemonte/Twinkle

This library creates several `CAEmitterLayers` and animates them generating a sparkle (aka glitter) effect.

```
let emitterCells: [CAEmitterCell] = [CAEmitterCell(), CAEmitterCell()]

for cell in emitterCells {

    cell.birthRate = 8
    cell.lifetime = 1.25
    cell.lifetimeRange = 0
    cell.emissionRange = (.pi / 4)
    cell.velocity = 2
    cell.velocityRange = 18
    cell.scale = 0.65
    cell.scaleRange = 0.7
    cell.scaleSpeed = 0.6
    cell.spin = 0.9
    cell.spinRange = .pi
    cell.color = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.3).cgColor
    cell.alphaSpeed = -0.8
    cell.contents = twinkleImage?.cgImage
    cell.magnificationFilter = TwinkleLayerMagnificationFilter
    cell.minificationFilter = TwinkleLayerMinificationFilter
    cell.isEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain further? @PTVyas